# Setting file permissions using java.io.File methods

Tags: java, io

I'm using `java.io.File` methods: `setReadable`, `setWritable`, `setExecutable` to set file permissions. However, in spite of using these methods the permissions are always set to the default settings. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods are not always supported by the underlying filesystem.  E.g. it's not possible to make a point unreadable in NTFS on Windows XP.

There's more information here: [www.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/enhancements-136788.html), 
under "Setting File and Directory Permissions"

Comment: It's not possible to make a file unreadable in Windows NTFS.  The methods ought to return `true` or `false`, depending upon whether they worked or not.

Comment: I believe that the article @andewmu linked to has been moved here: [More Enhancements in Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/enhancements-136788.html).  There's also the [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class of static methods, added in Java SE 7.